# Captivate LMS - Capture time spent per slide

Tags: moodle, scorm, elapsedtime, adobe-captivate

I am using Adobe Captivate to create a SCORM compliant e-learning module. This module is made up of interactive slides and will be accessed from Moodle. I would like to know if there is any way I can find out how much time my users spend on each slide of the module. I want to know what slides users spend the most time on and record these times for later analysis. Are there any Captivate options / question types /data logging I can use that will elicit the time spent per slide?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is cmi.interactions.n.latency. I don't know where you check this in moodle, but this is part of SCORM standard, so, it should be stored someplace.